# Correct REST API URL format for related objects

Tags: django, api, rest, url, relationship

I'm designing a REST API where, amongst others, there are two objects.

- `Journey`
- `Report`

For each `Journey` there are many `Reports` enroute, and each `Report` has exactly one associated `Journey`.

A user might create a `Journey` using the API as follows...

```
POST /journey/
```

Then retrieve the details...

```
GET /journey/1226/
```

The **first question** is, if a user wanted to post an `Report` to their `Journey`, which is the 'correct' URL structure that the API should impose? This seems intuitive to me...

```
POST /journey/1226/report/
```

...or is this the case...

```
POST /report/
```

...whereby in the latter, the `Journey` ID is passed in the request body somewhere?

The **second question** is, how might one go about implementing the first case in a tool such as the Django REST framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL/URI structure is almost completely irrelevant. It is nice to be able to read it, or easily change or even guess it, but that is it. There is no "requirement" official or unwritten how they should look like.

The point is however, that you *supply* the URIs to your clients in your responses. Each GET will get you a representation that contains links to the next "states" that your client can reach. This means the server has full control over URI structure, the client usually has to only know the "start" or "homepage" URI, and that's it.

Here is an article which discusses this question, has some good points: http://www.ben-morris.com/hackable-uris-may-look-nice-but-they-dont-have-much-to-do-with-rest-and-hateoas/

Pass for the second question :) I didn't use that particular framework.